# Question marks in filenames and Samba

Tags: filenames, samba, special-characters

I have smbd version 3.6.6 on Linux and mount the share on a FreeBSD system with `mount_smbfs`. When I try to copy (`cp`) a filename containing a question mark, I will get the error:

```
 No such file or directory
```

Renaming the files would be obviously possible, but sadly they are saved html pages referencing each other and I would also have to change the source code.

I know that question marks in filenames is a very bad style but aside from the samba-problem they don't cause any issues.

Disabling or enabling the option `display charset = utf-8` does not help.

Comment: Are you sure those filenames contain `?` characters? Is it not just `ls` or your terminal emulator printing a `?` in place of non-printable characters or non-characters? Do you still see a question mark if you run `ls | cat` or `ls | sed -n l`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas question marks still show up with these commands. They also show up in the GUI file manager (pcmanfm).

Comment: Are those question marks actually in the file name on the server, or are they replacements for non-ASCII characters? If the latter, check that the client and the server have consistent filename encoding settings. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358561/rename-file-with-weird-name-on-samba-mount for an issue of the same type.